# how can I match the documents and sort by values but then again return the filtered data of the highest value of a certain field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
// mongoose schema format

mongoose.Schema(
  {
    businessID: { type: String, index: true },
    userID: { type: String, index: true },
    userBusinessID: { type: Number, index: true },
    data: { type: String },
  }
);
```

```
db.data.find({})

[
  {
    businessID: 'B1',
    userID: 'U1',
    userBusinessID: 1,
    data: "hello1"
  },
  {
    businessID: 'B1',
    userID: 'U1',
    userBusinessID: 2,
    data: "hello2"
  },
  {
    businessID: 'B2',
    userID: 'U1',
    userBusinessID: 1,
    data: "hello4"
  },
  {
    businessID: 'B1',
    userID: 'U2',
    userBusinessID: 1,
    data: "hello5"
  },
]
```

```
// Expected return data of userID "U1"

[
  {
    businessID: 'B1',
    userID: 'U1',
    userBusinessID: 2, // notice that B1 & U1 has two docs, but the pipeline returns the doc with higher value
    data: "hello2"
  },
  {
    businessID: 'B2',
    userID: 'U1',
    userBusinessID: 1,
    data: "hello4"
  }
]
```

It can be worked on in application layer but I can't seem to think of any aggretation pipeline combination that can help with the behavior of:

1. match
2. sort by a particular field
3. return the highest matched field document if there are common matches

Comment: The logic here is not clear to me. Please explain how do you choose these 2 documents out of the original 4 documents. What is your `$match` query? What is your `$sort` query?

Comment: You can simply do: `db.collection.find({userID: "U1",  businessID: "B1" }).sort({userBusinessChatID: -1 })`

Comment: Your ` $match` query (using `$and`) returns 2 documents from your sample data. Is that what you want?

Comment: it return 3 documents, i.e. with extra document with `userBusinessID: 1`. I'm trying to remodel the output and ignore the smaller userBusinessID if there are common matches.

Comment: But there are only 2 documents with userID: "U1" **and** businessID: "B1"

Comment: It is not a problem to remove the duplication. Just provide the first match...your match query returns only 2 documents...

Comment: oops, there was a mistake on my comment above. It should be `{ $match: { userID: "U1" }  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {userID: "U1"}},
  {$sort: {userBusinessID: -1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {businessID: "$businessID", userID: "$userID"},
      data: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tfzEBkYb4nj)

Comment: wow, works like magic.
just a small question, about the mongoose schema, does it matter if `userBusinessID` has index: true? will the indexing be useful for this $group?

Comment: yes, it should be useful

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, in our case we returned the highest `userBusinessID` of the matches. Now, if I want to get the two highest matching documents, how can I work on that?
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vx2-dDu2nZ-
on reference to this playground, expected results are `hello2, hello3, hello4`

Comment: One option is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tXwwo_36Cbj), but if you have mongodb version 5.0 or higher you can do it more efficient

Comment: much thanks, it works like charm.
I see that there are API docs of aggregation pipeline all over the place in official MongoDB docs, but do you recommend something to start learning these stuffs deeper with real world examples?
where should I start from?

Comment: If you want real world problems you can start by picking questions here. you also have the answers :)